# Angular socket.io can't connect

Tags: socket.io, ionic-framework

I am quite new to node and socket.io, so be patient.

I have a small server running locally (just to see how it works):

```
"use strict";
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var server  = require('http').Server(app);
var io      = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('connected!');
  socket.on('add-customer', function(customer) {
    io.emit('notification', {
      message: 'new customer',
      customer: customer
    });
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});
server.listen(9000, function() {
  console.log('server up and running at 9000 port');
});
```

And I have a ionic app (uses angular) with the socket module [angular-socket-io](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io):

```
MyApp.factory('socket', function (socketFactory) {
    return socketFactory({
        ioSocket: io.connect('http://localhost') 
        //also tried to specify the port: localhost:9000
    });
});
```

And in my controller I just want to send a message to the server but **nothing is displayed in the console except for** `server up and running at 9000 port`:

```
MyApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, socket){
    $scope.users = [];
    socket.emit('add-customer', {test:'test'});
    socket.on('add-customer', {test:'test'}); // Desperation
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function (event) {
        socket.removeAllListeners();
    });
});
```

I have tried all tutorials and keep going back and forth...

My ionic app is served on port `8100` if helps.

What am I missing?

P.S: I don`t seem to see any attempt of any connection (see console screenshot)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to avoid using the angular module and use native:

```
MyApp.factory('socket', function ($rootScope) {
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:9000');
    return {
        on: function (eventName, callback) {
            socket.on(eventName, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    callback.apply(socket, args);
                });
            });
        },
        emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
            socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    if (callback) {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    }
                });
            })
        }
    };
});
```

Then in the controller use the object:

```
MyApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, socket){
    $scope.users = [];
    socket.emit('connection'); });
...
```

And the server side:

```
"use strict";
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var server  = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('connected!');
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});
server.listen(9000, function() {
  console.log('server up and running at 9000 port');
});
```

Comment: If this is the solution you went with, then you can "accept" your own answer by clicking the green checkmark to the left of it.

Answer (score 1):

If the web page that you are trying to make the socket.io connection from is on port 8100 and you're trying to make the socket.io connection to port 9000, that is a cross-origin request and the browser will not allow that unless you enable that with CORS on your socket.io server.

If you look in the browser debug console, you will probably see an error about a cross origin connection being denied access.

You will either need to have your socket.io server come from the same server that your web page is coming from and adjust the client-side connection accordingly or you will need enable CORs from the desired origin on your socket.io server.

```
"use strict";
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var server  = require('http').Server(app);

// allow the ionic page from port 8100 to connect to this server
// using CORS
var opts = {origins: "http://yourhostname:8100"};

var io = require('socket.io')(server, opts);
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('connected!');
  socket.on('add-customer', function(customer) {
    io.emit('notification', {
      message: 'new customer',
      customer: customer
    });
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});
server.listen(9000, function() {
  console.log('server up and running at 9000 port');
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work with: `var opts = {origins: "localhost:8100"};`
In the console I can't see any connection attempt or anything...

Comment: @KA_lin - Origins have to be a real URL with protocol such as `http://localhost:8100`.  My example originally did not show that - I've edited to show that.

Comment: I'll check it out later. Although I think I have tried that but I'll let you know. Thanks for your patience

Comment: Unfortunately even with the full address I can't conect : `var opts = {origins: "http://localhost:8100"};`

Comment: @KA_lin - What errors do you see in the debug log on the client?

Comment: I don't get any errors...that is why is so baffling... I got it to work without the angular plugin and using the io global variable in a factory. Thank you for your time. You could write an answer with avoiding the plugin, use a facory for socket (http://briantford.com/blog/angular-socket-io), specify the address with the right port and I will mark your answer (if you want or I will add the solution as an answer-good start for noobs like myself)

Comment: @KA_lin - So the issue was something to do with Angular?  I guess you should write your own answer for that.  I would appreciate at least an upvote for helping you though.